# Strange behavior by jsp compiler

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I have the following code in my jsp scriptlet (inside <% %>):

```
boolean blockScreen = false;
    if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelA) || title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelB))
    {
    blockScreen = true;
    }
```

The java file generated corresponding to the above jsp contains following code(identical):

```
boolean blockScreen = false;
        if(title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelA) || title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelB))
        {
        blockScreen = true;
        }
```

But when I debug, I can not see the blockScreen variable. I decompiled the class file, and can see the following code:

```
   if(!title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelA))
            if(!title.equalsIgnoreCase(labelB));
```

Not sure why the blockScreen variable is getting cleaned out in the class file. The same variable is used further down in a c:choose tag:

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${blockScreen==true}">
<!--do something -->    
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<!--do something else -->
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I am using JBoss EAP 6 server.

Any help in this regard appreciated.

Comment: How do you use the variable in `<c:out>` tag?

Comment: Sorry the variable is used in a c:choose tag. I have updated the question with the c:choose code.

Comment: Run the class file with javap tool and see if the variable is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EL expression `${blockScreen==true}` uses a request attribute named `blockScreen`, not a scriptlet variable of the same name, therefore compiler is free to optimize away the usused variable.

If you want to use a scriptlet variable instead, try `<c:when test="<%= blockScreen %>">`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR the scope of your variable is local to scriplet (and generated servlet), so it is **NOT** visible/accessible in the rest of the page. For this reason compiler will remove it completely.
If you **can** use identically named variable somewhere else in the page that means that it is declared page-wide variable somewhere else...

Comment: But shouldn't it cause compilation error when the same variable is used in the c:choose tag further below?

Comment: No compilation error because you are declaring more restrictively scoped local variable.